# Example of analytic piecewise-defined function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-analysis

Does there exist an analytic everywhere, piecewise-defined function $f$ such that:

$f(x) = g(x)$ for $x < k$
$f(x) = h(x)$ for $x>k$
$f(x) = r$ for $x=k$

With $g \ne h $ ($g$ not the same function as $h$)

If it exists, what is such an example?

Comment: What do you mean with "everywhere piecewise-defined"?

Comment: I mean "analytic everywhere" and "picewise-defined"

Comment: I'm assuming that the first block should read f(x)=g(h) for x<k

Comment: Could some edit it to say f(x)=g(x) for x<k, then newline, cant get it to work

Comment: Do you also want g and h to be analytic everywhere?

Comment: not necessarily, but I want f to be

Comment: Well then: f(x) = g(x) = r; h(x) = r if x > k, and 0 if x <= k. Or did you want g and h to be continuous? I can do that too :-)

Comment: I want g not equal to h

Comment: OK, then we're done, aren't we?

Comment: What is the definion of a truncation at level k?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g$ and $h$ are not necessarily analytic, then just take an arbitrary analytic function $f$ with $f(k) = r$. Define $g$ and $h$ to be

$$ g(x) := f(x) \chi(k-x) \qquad h(x) := f(x) \chi(x-k) $$

where $\chi$ is a cut-off function, that is: $\chi(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 0$, $\chi(x) = 0$ for $x \leq -1$ and $0 < \chi(x) < 1$ for $-1 < x < 0$. Then you have all your desired properties. You can choose $\chi$ to be continuous, or even smooth.

---

If $g$ and $h$ are analytic, then the answer is no. Real analytic functions have the unique continuation property. That is, if a real analytic function is zero on an open set, it must be zero everywhere. Then since $f$ is everywhere analytic, and $g$ is everywhere analytic, their difference $f-g$ is also analytic, and vanishes for $x < k$. This implies that $f=g$ everywhere. Similarly $f =h$ everywhere and $g$ and $h$ must coincide.

Comment: I am almost completely sure (eg. Rudin) that the property you describe with respect to real analytic functions, actually applies ONLY to holomorphic functions? Which are generally more 'rigid' than real analytic functions, i.e. they adhere to more rules.

Comment: @user71551 The open set condition for holomorphic functions comes from a weaker condition that any holomorphic function with a limit point in its domain of zeros must be zero everywhere. If you take a real analytic function that vanishes on an open set, it can be extended to a holomorphic function on some open set in $\mathbb{C}$, in which case the limit point argument would show that it is zero everywhere (including on its domain in the $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2):

Such a function will be trivially impossible unless you relax the requirement that an analytic function be equal to its taylor series in a neighborhood of any point. Once that restriction is relaxed, the following is an example of a piecewise function with all derivatives continuous:

$f(0) = 0$

$f(x) = g(x) = e^{(\tfrac{-1}{x^2})}$ for $x < 0$

$f(x) = 2*g(x)$ for $x > 0$

All derivatives are continuous, passing through (0, 0). You can create other examples using the strange function $e^{(\tfrac{-1}{x^2})}$